# How to call String from Shared Preference and change my server URL based on it in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need to use my shared preference stored string in this const String

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3joha.png)

Comment: Constants are constant, defined at compile time. Shared settings are modifiable at runtime. You can't define a constant non-constant thing.

Comment: @DenisRamdan did you delete a comment beforehand? also, comments support formatting: `\`code\``, just put it in backticks :)

Comment: @JustLearnedIt I forgot to add that think, but unfortunately I can't do edit anymore :(

Comment: @JustLearnedIt already explained why it can't be done, maybe you can try using `static`, like this => `static String baseUrl(String sharedPrefString) => 'https//yourserver.id/$sharedPrefString';`